# Loopback adapter faster as administrator

Tags: performance, server, window, loopback, administrator

I have two applications that use the local loopback adapter (127.0.0.1) to exchange data. Both applications run on a windows server 2019 platform. When I run both applications as administrator I see a significant performance increase (~50%) compared to when I run this as a power user.

Can somebody explain to me why this is? is there a setting that limits the throughput of users?

I would like to run the applications as (power) user with the performance increase that I have when I run it as administrator.

Comment: As a user you might experience context switches to more privilegere users/drivers, that you will not see if you already are in admin.

Comment: Just tried on another platform and on this platform there is **no difference** between the power user and administrator user; Is there a way to compare users/groups between two platforms?